# How can I pause the jquery mouseenter "counter" while the animation is running?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, mouseleave, mouseenter

I have a problem with the jquery mouseenter and mouseleave. I've got a linkbutton which is sliding to the left when you hover over it to show the link-picture. For a more fluid animation its waiting at least one second before sliding back. But due to the delay its firing when you move over it for more then once.
I've searched about this topic for days but there were no solutions. Now I thought about solving this with a condition. Here is my code so far.

```
    if( $(".block_dev").is ('animated') ) {} else {  

    $(".border_dev").mouseenter(function() {  
        $(".block_dev").animate({"left": "-=41px"}, "slow")  
                       .wait(); })  
                    .mouseleave(function() {  
        $(".block_dev").animate({"left": "+=41px"}, "slow")  
                       .wait(); }) }
```

.wait() is the timeout script. With the if condition I want it to do nothing (no new mouseenter counts) and only when its finished it should start again, but its not working.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: thanks for the tip, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/eUkE4/ it works similar to my website version of it. edit: sry updated with the still not working if condition. http://jsfiddle.net/eUkE4/2/

Comment: I can't see an `if` statement in that.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you just meant `.is(':animated')` since just `animated` by itself is not a valid selector. (That would in theory select tags like `<animated ...>` in the same way `p` selects tags like `<p ...>`, and of course that's not at all what you had in mind.)

Comment: Wrapping the original event bindings in even that isn't going to do much.

Comment: thanks! I updated it! but its still not doing "nothing" but its just ignoring the condition..

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your conditional *inside* the event handlers (not around your creation of them), and use `':animated'` (rather than `'animated'`).

Comment: thanks! I'm trying it right now. When I found a working solution I will update it!

Comment: Its working! thanks a lot! working script: http://jsfiddle.net/eUkE4/3/ ..but without the timeout, because its not recognized as animated when you're firing over it.